# Is $Y_1,Y_2$ independent uniform $[0,1]$ random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose we have $Y_1,Y_2$ taking value in $[0,1]$. The given condition is that for all disjoint intervals $J_k,k=1,\dots, n$ s.t. $\cup_{k=1}^n J_k=[0,1]$, we have

$$P( \forall k, n_k \text{ of }Y_1,Y_2 \text{ is in } J_k) = \frac{2}{\Pi_{k=1}^n n_k!}\Pi_{k=1}^n|J_k|^{n_k} ,$$

where $\sum n_k =2$ and $| \cdot |$ is the length of the interval.

I wonder whether this condition implies that $Y_1,Y_2$ are distributed as independent uniform $[0,1]$ variables. The reverse way is obvious but not sure how to use the given condition to show $Y_1,Y_2$ are independent uniforms.

Comment: But if $n_k=2$ for some $k$, there shouldn't be a factor of $2$?

Comment: Right, Let me adjust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the case. The same probabilities also hold for $Y_\lt=\min(Y_1,Y_2)$ and $Y_\gt=\max(Y_1,Y_2)$ (where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independently uniformly distributed), yet those are not independently uniformly distributed.